# Not getting results when row count on another table is 0

Tags: mysql, select, count, left-join

I'm building a discussion board... I have a table containing the posts and another containing comments... foreign id is the `post_id`. Now, I'm trying to sort the posts based on number of comments each has. Query I'm currently using:

```
SELECT username, posts.post_id, category_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(posts.datetime) AS datetime, posts.body, posts.owner_id, COUNT(comment_id) AS number
FROM posts, comments, user
WHERE posts.post_id = comments.post_id AND posts.owner_id = user.`id`
GROUP BY comments.post_id
ORDER BY number DESC
```

The query works fine, but the problem is that posts that don't have comments are not selected. I want to display posts not minding if they have comments or not but I want to sort them by number of comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LEFT Join. Your From/where joint is equivalent to INNER JOIN :

```
SELECT username, p.post_id, category_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.datetime) AS datetime,
   p.body, p.owner_id, COUNT(comment_id) AS number
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN comments c ON p.post_id = c.post_id
LEFT JOIN user u ON p.owner_id = u.`id`
GROUP BY c.post_id
ORDER BY number DESC
```

Comment: This does it. Thanks. Remove the ',' immediately after "FROM posts p,"

Comment: This is a mistake that everyone does at least once in the SQL. Prefer to call JOIN in the future.

Answer (score 2):

USE **LEFT JOIN** on comments table

Try this:

```
SELECT username, p.post_id, category_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.datetime) AS DATETIME, 
       p.body, p.owner_id, COUNT(comment_id) AS number
FROM posts p 
INNER JOIN user u ON p.owner_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN comments c ON p.post_id = c.post_id 
GROUP BY p.post_id
ORDER BY number DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks... perfect. Now, I don't know which answer to accept :s